# Tex Writer on iPad

Tags: compiling, editors, ipad

I've just purchased Tex Writer for an iPad Air, I synced it with my Dropbox account, downloaded a .tex file, hit the play button (which I assumed is for compiling) and nothing happened. Am I missing something?

I have an \include for a preamble and thought that was the problem. Well, I downloaded it and nothing. I copied the preamble and deleted the include thing but still nothing...

I need to be able to compile tex files, at least I need to know if I'm misspelling something so when I run it in my laptop, everything's fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to hit the button on the left-hand side of "play" to see the resulting pdf file (an the button on the left-hand side of that to see the log file)

Comment: Did you install any TeX/LaTeX distribution?

Comment: Yes, I was hitting the button that looks like a 'play' button but still nothing. The weird thing is that I downloaded the tex file again but put it in a different folder and it started compiling. It seemed to download a couple of packages and at last it didn't created a PDF but at least showed me a bunch of errors. That's something!

Comment: IMHO we would need much more information to detect the problem and find a solution, but the user has been seen last 2015. So I vote to close the question as unclear.